# is there any way to find last 3 aws launch template version using python?

Tags: python-3.x

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import boto3

import sys

ec2 = boto3.client('ec2', region_name=region)

template_versions = ec2.describe_launch_template_versions(Versions=["$Latest"])
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

To answer the question, I would say that there is no easy why to get this.
You would need to do

```py
template_versions = ec2.describe_launch_template_versions( LaunchTemplateId="...", )
```

(you could also use `LaunchTemplateName`)

then get back all versions.

In theory, you could get back the latest version like you are above and then get that version number. Then subtract 3 and set the min version and max version. The issue is you can delete versions. So you could say a min and max and only get 1, 2, or 3 results back. I would say if you want 3 results find the latest version number -10 and if less than 1 set min to 1.  Then sort the array based on the version number.

So something like

```py
latest_version = 18
template_versions = ec2.describe_launch_template_versions( LaunchTemplateId="...", MinVersion="8",MaxVersion="18" ).get("LaunchTemplateVersions")

template_versions.sort(key=lambda x: x["VersionNumber"], reverse=True)
```

https://www.techiedelight.com/sort-list-of-objects-python/

In theory, the first 3 should be the latest 3 versions. But again it is possible to get a number under 3.

https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#EC2.Client.describe_launch_template_versions